# How to have editable fields through liferay search container?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am new to liferay development.

I have done good work to display the liferay grid by using liferay search container.

But now the requirement is that some of the fields in the grid should have provision to be modified by user.

Is it possible through liferay search container or do I need to follow any other approach to achieve editable liferay grid?

Comment: you may display fields as input text instead of label, and using some ajax mechanism you can save row data

Comment: i am displaying the column data by using this tag "<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text value="<%=usersDetails.getName()%>" name="Name"/>".To display the field as input text i have tried <liferay-ui:input-field/> but it did not work.Can you elaborate bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp` tag or directly use `<aui-input />` inside the `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text` tag.

Example (I have included code comments with the code sample for your understanding):

```
<liferay-ui:search-container
    emptyResultsMessage="no-assets-selected"
    iteratorURL="<%= configurationRenderURL %>"
    total="<%= assetEntries.size() %>"
>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= assetEntries.subList(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getResultEnd()) %>"
    />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
        className="com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetEntry"
        escapedModel="<%= true %>"
        keyProperty="entryId"
        modelVar="assetEntry"
    >

        <aui:form action="doesThisWork?">

            <%-- this is the normal way --%>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="type"
                value="<%= assetRendererFactory.getTypeName(locale, false) %>"
            />

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-date
                name="modified-date"
                value="<%= assetEntry.getModifiedDate() %>"
            />

            <%--
                this is the JSP way 
                You can include anything in the JSP like <input /> fields, textarea, select drop-down etc.
            --%>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
                align="right"
                path="/html/portlet/asset_publisher/asset_selection_action.jsp"
            />

            <%--
                Here is including <input /> field inside the column text field.
                Notice I am not using the "value" attribute of this tag, instead I am
                writing HTML inside the body of this tag.
            --%>
            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="type"
            >
                <aui:input type="text" name="enterSomething" value="I can enter input here" />
                <aui:input type="text" name="enterSomething" value="<%=assetEntry.getTitle %>" />
                <aui:input type="hidden" name="enterSomething" value="this is a hidden field of the form" />
            </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

        </aui:form>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator paginate="<%= total > SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA %>" />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

In the above example, there would be a `<form>` for each row, so you can have a submit button at the end of each row to submit the data for that row.

But you can do it in other ways as well:

1. You can write the `<form>` outside the Search-container tag so that you just have one form and can submit all the row data togather
2. Or else you can have a `<form>` somewhere down the page and through javascript populate the value in the form and then submit.
3. Or else you can use ajax and other stuff to accomplish this. Or a combination of several approaches.

I leave this upto you to figure out.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I have not test this code. But as per my understanding this should work. :-)</sub>